# RDWeb icons showing rdp instead of native icons

Tags: remoteapp

I have a server with Windows 08 R2 on it and it is dedicated as an RDS server for RDWeb. The programs that have been installed show as RDP icons instead of their native icons. I have tried several things to try and resolve this but I am drawing a blank on what is causing this issue. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved!

This was fixed by adding the corresponding ICO file to c:\Windows\System32. This allows RDWeb to access the files from a local directory instead of a network path.